# JMSCC0008: This connection is closed while calling JMSTemplate.send method

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am  facing an intermittent issue in an application where we used to connect to IBM MQ and we have two queues one for sending the reply and another one is to listen message from MQ ,listening message seems not having any issue but while sending the reply it seems the connection gets closed sometimes and thus resulting in below error in logs

```
 JMSCC0008: This connection is closed.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0008: This connection is closed.
An application called a method that must not be used after the connection is closed.
Ensure that the connection is not closed before calling the method.
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: JMSCC0008: This connection is closed.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0008: This connection is closed.
An application called a method that must not be used after the connection is closed.
Ensure that the connection is not closed before calling the method.
```

Comment: Do you see any 2009 errors before this?  Any errors reported in the queue manager logs?  Does the connection pass through a firewall or balancer?  What is the `HBINT` set to on the `SVRCONN` channel?

Comment: You have not posted your code, so I am guessing - your connection object may be going out of scope and hence the connection to queue manager is getting closed?

Comment: @Priyank can you review and respond to the questions I asked?

Comment: @JoshMC yes the connection passes through the firewalls and HBINT value is set to 280

Comment: Try dropping it to 30 or 60.

Comment: I can do it but will not have any implications on the application working

Comment: @Shashi I can't paste the code as there is some constrant if possible can you please let me know how i can check it

Comment: You will have to review your code and see if there is any case the connections getting closed.